# Manual component refresh after succesfull api call

Tags: angular, api, page-refresh

So I've written my own api and I do quite a lot of api calls. The problem is that my components don't update when the calls finish. I've been doing a bit of research and this is what I've come up with:

```js
  onSubmit() {
    if (this._user) {
      this._commentDataService
        .postComment(
          this.imageId,
          new Comment(
            this.loggedInUser.firstName + ' ' + this.loggedInUser.lastName,
            this.messageForm.value.message,
            new Date(),
            this.imageId,
            this.loggedInUser.id
          )
        )
        .subscribe(com => {
          console.log(com);
          this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
        });
    } else {
      this.openSnackBar('You need to be logged in to send a message.');
    }
  }
```

But apperently, the `markForCheck()` doesn't refresh my component after finishing the post request:

```js
  postComment(imageId: number, comment: Comment): Observable<Comment> {
    return this.http.post<Comment>(
      `${environment.apiUrl}/images/${imageId}/comments`,
      comment.toJSON()
    );
  }
```

I also need this tho happen for a PUT and a DELETE (those one I haven't tested it yet)

Could you please help me?

Next part of the question (now that my component refreshes :) ) 
So when I POST/PUT on a comment, it wors absolutely fine, but when I try to delete a post, it deletes the right post in the database but it visually deletes the comment right under the the comment that I want to delete. When I refresh, the right comment gets visually deleted and the comment that was visually deleted is back in it's place. I don't know why it does this (maybe this has something to do with the fact that the order of the comments changes sometimes (I haven't found out in what condition they change or why)
code:

#### DeleteCommentComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MatSnackBar, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { CommentDataService } from '../comment-data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-delete-comment',
  templateUrl: './delete-comment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./delete-comment.component.css']
})
export class DeleteCommentComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DeleteCommentComponent>,
    private _commentDataService: CommentDataService,
    private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  cancel() {
    this.openSnackbar('Comment did not get deleted.');
    this.onNoClick();
  }

  delete() {
    this._commentDataService
      .deleteComment(this.data.comment.myImageId, this.data.comment.id)
      .subscribe(c => {
        console.log(c);
        if (c) {
          this.data.array.pop(c);
          this.openSnackbar('Comment succesfully deleted.');
        } else {
          this.openSnackbar(
            'Something went wrong deleting the comment, please try again.'
          );
        }
      });
    this.onNoClick();
  }

  private onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  private openSnackbar(message: string) {
    this._snackBar.open(message, 'Close', { duration: 2000 });
  }
}
```

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Delete a comment</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>
  Are you sure you want to delete this comment?
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-raised-button class="noBtn right" (click)="cancel()">No</button>
  <button mat-raised-button class="yesBtn" (click)="delete()">Yes</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

The method that opens up this dialog:

```js
  openDeleteDialog(comment: Comment) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteCommentComponent, {
      width: '300px',
      height: '200px',
      data: { comment, array: this.comments }
    });
  }
```

This gets called when you click on a the delete button:

```
<div class="overflow">
  <div
    fxLayout="row"
    fxLayoutAlign="space-between"
    *ngFor="let comment of comments"
  >
    <div>
      <div class="commentDiv" data-cy="comments">
        <span class="user left">{{ comment.author }}: </span>
        <span>{{ comment.content }}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="iconDiv right" *ngIf="isAuthor(comment)">
        <mat-icon class="edit" (click)="openChangeDialog(comment)"
          >edit</mat-icon
        ><mat-icon class="delete" (click)="openDeleteDialog(comment)"
          >delete</mat-icon
        >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<form [formGroup]="messageForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" data-cy="commentForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      aria-label="Message"
      placeholder="Message"
      type="text"
      class="browser-default"
      formControlName="message"
    />
    <mat-error
      *ngIf="
        messageForm.get('message')['errors'] &&
        messageForm.get('message').touched
      "
    >
      {{ getErrorMessage(messageForm.get('message')['errors']) }}
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  <button mat-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="!messageForm.valid">
    <mat-icon>send</mat-icon>
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't see you mutating any data in your component, only making a POST request and logging the comment, so it makes sense that `markForCheck()` won't do a thing. No data in your component (any of your component's properties) was changed. Do you store posted comments in some array as a property in your component? If so, add the posted comment to that array and the component should update automatically if you're using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default`. You could also make a GET request to fetch all comments from your server right after posting a comment, but that feels like a worse option.

Comment: @AmitB.I don't keep an array of elements, instead I use a HttpGet to my comments (and images) from my backend sql database

Comment: In which cases do you expect to make a GET request for your comments? Only when the logged in user posts a comment, when notified from the server using WebSocket/SocketIO/etc..., or do you poll for new comments?

Comment: @AmitB. I've added what you told me: an array with the comments in (actually I already had one) and the post works amazing but when I try delete, for some reason it deletes the correct comment but visually, the wrong comment gets deleted. After a refresh, the correct comment is deleted and the wrongly deleted comment has come back

Comment: Show us your code so we could better understand why that happens

Comment: @AmitB. Done, sorry for the late responses, I'm currently nearing my first exam and I still ahve a lot of work to do!, thanks anyway for helping